# What Target Framework and References to use when compiling a DLL for Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have some scripts which I use normally in Unity 2019.4 and also compile into a separate DLL to distribute without the source code. Everything was working until I started using `System.Array.Empty<T>()` in a few places which works fine in Unity but is preventing me from compiling the separate DLL.

- Originally, I had the Target Framework set to `Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries`, but that's now giving me the error: `'Array' does not contain a definition for 'Empty'`
- Apparently `Array.Empty` was added in `.NET Framework 4.6`, but if I set the Target Framework to that (or later) I get: `The type 'ISet<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'` from everywhere I use a `HashSet<T>` (even though I'm not using `ISet<>` directly).
- If I manually add a reference to the `System.dll` from the Unity install directory, it gives the exact same error but says `ISet<>` is in the `netstandard` dll now.
- Adding a reference to `netstandard.dll` from the Unity install directory gives `Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported`.
- Trying to fix that by referencing `mscorlib.dll` gives `The type 'HashSet<T>' exists in both 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`

So what Target Framework and References am I supposed to be using to compile a DLL for Unity 2019.4?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by copying one of the csproj files that Unity generates for an Assembly Definition and removing the stuff I don't need.

The main difference seems to be the inclusion of this block:

```
      <PropertyGroup>
        <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
        <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
        <AddAdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences>false</AddAdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences>
        <ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades>
        <ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

Which I'm guessing allows it to also define its own references to `mscorlib.dll`, `netstandard.dll`, and `System.Core.dll` without having them conflict with the ones imported by the framework.